# JavaScript arrow functions without parentheses for example functionName = > {}

Tags: javascript, arrow-functions

I found this problem on a website with javascript exercises :

Write a JavaScript program to chain asynchronous functions.

So you are given a list with functions and you have to make a function that executes each function of the array, I tried to do this :

```
let chainAsyncFunc = (arrayWithFunctions) => {
    return arrayWithFunction.map((func) => func())
}
```

But their answer to the exercise is this :

```
const chainAsync = fns => {
  let curr = 0;
  const next = () => fns[curr++](next);
  next();
};
```

Which I don't really understand

And the answer looks like this:

```
chainAsync([
  next => {
    console.log('0 seconds');
    setTimeout(next, 1000);
  },
  next => {
    console.log('1 second');
  }
]);
```

What is 'next => {}'
If it would be an arrow function it should look like this next = () => {//code//} even without parameters

Comment: The exercise you are describing changes multiple times throughout your post. Is it an array of `async` functions or not? Why do the functions in the array suddenly all have a convenient support for `next`?

Comment: `next => {…}` is equivalent to `(next) => {…}`. No, unlike the `const next` in the first snippet it's not an assignment/initialisation of a variable. It's just a function expression that's part of the array literal.

Comment: Didn't the exercise also specify what they meant by "asynchronous function"?

Comment: The exercise sounds exactly like this :  Write a JavaScript program to chain asynchronous functions.

Answer (score 4):

The parenthesis around a lambda function's arguments are optional when you have a single parameter.  So, `a => {}` and `(a) => {}` are equivalent.  The parenthesis are required when the lambda:

- takes no arguments:  `() => { /* code */ }`
- takes more than one argument:  `(a, b) => { /* code */ }`
- takes advantage of [object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) in the signature.  For example:

```
var exampleFunc = ({a, b}) => console.log(`A = ${a}, B = ${b}`)
exampleFunc({a: 1, b: 2})
```

This will print: `A = 1, B = 2`

Answer (score 2):

In arrow functions, there are some syntax tricks to make it cleaner.

**For example**

If you have only one parameter in the function you could not writhe the parentheses.

```
const foo = param => {return param}
```

In the example you mentioned if the return line is one line you can make the code cleaner by typing a one-line function and don't type the return key word.

```
const foo = param => param
/*This is equivilant to the example above*/
```

to know more check this **[link](https://javascript.info/arrow-functions-basics)**